# How to replace the string and put new values using php regex

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following string

> "Enter Contarct Fields wherever you want and enclose it with {}.You can use field's id or field's fieldcode for example {25} or {FIELD_CONTRACTTEXT}"

I want to replace this `{25}` and `{FIELD_CONTRACTTEXT}` with their equivalent value from databse.
Say `25` is a ID so I wanted to put name of the field of which `25` is the ID of.

There are many examples of replacing curly braces but no solution is there for replacing content like this. Please help me, I have tried many things.

PS: Please keep in mind that occurrence of `{}` is dynamic and `25` will not be a static number and there can be multiple `{}` in a string.

Comment: *i have tried many things*... please post them (or the most relevant/successful ones so far). What is it *explicitly* that you are having problems with?

Comment: Have a look at [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_match_all() to find the occurrences, use this array to find the values in the database and then str_replace to replace each value after that.

To begin with you will need to fetch all the occurrences:

```
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

The matches array will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {}
            [1] => {25}
            [2] => {FIELD_CONTRACTTEXT}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 25
            [2] => FIELD_CONTRACTTEXT
        )

)
```

You can then cylce through the array to find the individual elements that need to be replaced.

You can use the following to check the database and then replace values:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("data");

$string = "Enter Contarct Fields wherever you want and enclose it with {}.You can use field's id or field's fieldcode for example {25} or {FIELD_CONTRACTTEXT}";

preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE `element`='".addslashes($match)."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==1){
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        str_replace($string, "{".$match."}", $row['value']);
    }
}

echo $string; //echos final output with replaced values
```